# JPA 2.0 project not working in ant build

Tags: java, jpa, ant, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA 2.0 project that I am compiling with ant. The project is an EJB module contained in an EAR with the persistence.xml file located in the EAR's lib folder. for some reason, even though the classpath includes the correct JPA 2.0 compliant jar files (j2ee.jar from websphere v8 runtime libraries: i've checked the jar itself and the JPA 2 stuff is definitely there), The build fails when it comes across anything JPA 2.0 specific. is there something i need to include in my source code that tells the compiler that this is a jpa 2 project? is there an ant setting missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was due to a conflicting spring persistence jar with JPA 1.0 located on the classpath, This jar was being preferred over the correct jar and caused any JPA 2.0 specific code to have a compile error. After checking that this file had no projects depending on it, i removed the jar from the library and it compiled correctly.